# Properties of the square root of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

For PCA we have that

$\Lambda^{-1/2} \cdot \Lambda \cdot \Lambda^{-1/2} = I$

Where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal eigenvalue matrix. Is it always the case that

$A^{-1/2} \cdot A \cdot A^{-1/2} = I$

for any matrix $A$?

Comment: You need $A^{-1/2}$ to exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A^{1/2}$ is invertible and satisfies $A^{1/2} A^{1/2} = A$, then
$$A^{-1/2} A A^{-1/2} = A^{-1/2} A^{1/2} A^{1/2} A^{-1/2} = \cdots$$